# Quadratic congruence relation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there a general formula for solving quadratic congruence relation like $ax^2-bx+c = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

For example, I am trying to solve $x^2-3x+2 = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{200}$. What kind of tools I need to solve it?

Comment: In this case there is a method, based on the factorization $(x-1)(x-2)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are techniques, but no general formula. In this case there is a method, based on the factorization $(x-1)(x-2)$.

For any $x$, the numbers $x-1$ and $x-2$ are relatively prime. Note that $200=2^3\cdot 5^2$, and work modulo $8$ and $25$ separately.

Since $x-1$ and $x-2$ are relatively prime, we have $(x-1)(x-2)\equiv 0\pmod{8}$ if and only if $x\equiv 1\pmod{8}$ or $x\equiv 2\pmod{8}$.

Similarly,  we have $(x-1)(x-2)\equiv 0\pmod{25}$ if and only if $x\equiv 1\pmod{25}$ or $x\equiv 2\pmod{25}$.

That gives $4$ possibilities:

(i) $x\equiv 1\pmod{8}$, $x\equiv 1\pmod{25}$;

(i) $x\equiv 2\pmod{8}$, $x\equiv 2\pmod{25}$;

(iii) $x\equiv 1\pmod{8}$, $x\equiv 2\pmod{25}$;

(iv) $x\equiv 2\pmod{8}$, $x\equiv 1\pmod{25}$.

Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, or inspection, we can then write down the $4$ solutions modulo $200$.

The solutions to (i) and (ii) are trivial. For (iii), the solution is (by inspection) $177$ (modulo $200$. We leave (iv) to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just apply the general formula and work in $\mathbb Z_{200}$ (as far as possible):
$$
x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\mod 200
$$
The square root doesn't always exist and calculating them isn't very easy, but it can be [done](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Complexity_of_finding_square_roots). Sometimes there are no solutions and sometimes there are multiple solutions. Calculate the possible values for $x$ for each of the square roots. Division by $2$ isn't trivial too, because $200$ is even ($\gcd (200,2)\neq 1$). Therefore, when calculating $x=\frac k2\mod 200$, for even $x$ it can be $\frac k2$ or $\frac k2+100$, because $2\cdot(\frac k2+100)=k\mod 200$. For odd $x$, $\frac x2$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get something better is
$ax^2-bx+c=0\Rightarrow4a^2x^2-4abx+4ac=0\Rightarrow(2ax-b)^2=b^2-4ac=D$
So, if the first congruence has a solution mod $n$ then there must be an integer $y$
with $y^2=D$ holding true.

In other words $D$ must be a quadratic residue mod $n$.
(which sometimes is impossible for some $n$)